# Returned dynamic string as JSX, rendered as imported components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Suppose I have some process that generates some JSX dynamically but as a literal string, is it possible to return it as JSX **that renders imported components**, Material UI in this case?

With the below I can only get unstyled markup to display.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class Testsp extends React.Component<ITestspProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITestspProps> {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.someConvolutedProcess()} />
  }

  someConvolutedProcess() {
    let generatedJSX = '<Button color="primary">Hello World... Again</Button>';
    return {__html: generatedJSX};
  }
}
```

With the below I have to provide element as JSX, not a string

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)
```

I know my approach is weird but I have a niche case

Comment: You could possibly pipe the JSX source code string through Babel with the @babel/preset-react enabled and eval the output maybe? If that content is coming from user input this would obviously be a massive security risk, but if it's your content, this could work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in option to generate JSX from a string (string-to-JSX).

Note that you actually want to generate React element (`React.createElement`) from a string (as JSX is only [syntactic sugar](http://syntactic%20sugar))

- `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` accepts only HTML elements, **not JSX**.
- `ReactDOMServer` is for rendering component to static markup, i.e **JSX-to-string**, **JSX-to-HTML**.